# Manipulate multiple Aerospike Sets consistently using a single UDF

Tags: lua, user-defined-functions, aerospike

Is there a way to write a single Aerospike UDF(in lua), which has the ability to consistently manipulate mulitple aerospike sets(not records).

Example:-

I have Aerospike Sets {P, Q}.
I have to manipulate a record, Rp of Set P, and a record, Rq of Set Q in a single UDF.
If any of the set manipulation fails, both set records should revert to the original state, i.e. consistency should be maintained.

Any way out?

Comment: a multi-record update via UDF is not possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this. A record UDF allows you to manipulate a single record. A stream UDF allows you to build aggregate functions like SUM, COUNT, MIN, MAX, AVG, but they're read-only.